# How can I send SMS from my PC using my Android Phone (Galaxy S3)

Tags: windows-7, android, sms, galaxy-s3

I've been a long-time Nokia fan, but finally succumbed to the Samsung Galaxy S3's amazing screen, & Android's Open community.

One feature I use a lot (about a hundred times a day...) is Nokia PC Suite's ability to send SMS via the phone. It:

- Uses my phone's contact list.
- Notifies me when I get an sms.
- Allows me to send SMS using my PC's keyboard.
- Essentially turning SMS into just another IM medium I use on the PC.

How will I do this with the Samsung Galaxy S3 + Windows 7?

Comment: PS Yes this is a blatant copy/paste of a [similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/176818/how-can-i-send-sms-from-my-pc-using-my-iphone) I asked once about the iPhone I have since abandoned

Comment: This is a better question for [android.se]. Fortunately, it's already been asked and answered there: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-do-i-send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone

Comment: @AI-Everett: Didn't know that stack exchange existed, Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send SMSes from my computer through an Android phone?](http://superuser.com/questions/86076/how-do-i-send-smses-from-my-computer-through-an-android-phone)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Airdroid](http://airdroid.com/). It gives SMS and much more. And it is web based so you don't need to install a client on your machine.

Comment: Looks excellent! Will check it out soon!

Comment: Remote Web Desktop can also be used for sending and receiving SMS. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rm&hl=en

Comment: @criziot: Best app ever.

Comment: Yeah, best app ever I would say too !

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: Airdroid is a killer app. Though it's a privacy killer too...

Comment: Agreed, no privacy, but well done

Answer (score 4):

[MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/de/) the best software i know!!
Works really great, its fast and needs no installation. It works via USB, WLAN or bluetooth.

Comment: Oh, nice, I was using it with my Sony Ericsson, very good program. Didn't know they were now working with android phones.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need any extra apps or software as Samsung has this already covered. Samsung kies air is capable of doing all this & more using WiFi. It only works for Samsung devices tho. :))

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I have found is DeskSMS, by Clockworkmod. I believe it's 4.99$ per year. It allows you to SMS using a Google Chrome extension, or even by email. I haven't tried the Google Chat relay option, I disabled it.

Since it uses the internet, it will work over 3G or any  WiFi, not just a home LAN or usb like some other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my blog given below. I could do it with Samung Galaxy S2, it should work with S3 also.

http://mohanhobby.blogspot.in/2012/12/sending-sms-from-pc-to-samsung-galaxy.html

Comment: Linking without answering is [discouraged](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/500/is-downvoting-link-only-answers-acceptable), please quote the relevant information here.

Answer (score 0):

[PiceaHub](http://www.piceasoft.com/index.php?page=downloads) works fine. Send SMS, drag and drop videos and music to your Android from Youtube etc.