# How do I use my phone for SMS (while connected via bluetooth)

Tags: bluetooth, android, sms

I connected my Nexus 5 to my Windows 8 computer via bluetooth, with the hopes that I could do 2 things.

- Use my computer to send SMS messages
- Use me computer as a headset (with my microphone and speakers).

You can see below that I've synced my phone via bluetooth.
In the properties of the phone it shows 2 services. Remote contro, and MAP SMS.

1. How do I send SMS from my computer? (VIA Bluetooth, NOT internet services)
2. How do I use my computer as a headset? (VIA Bluetooth, NOT internet services)

I looked in the Windows 8 app store for SMS apps, but they all seem to use internet services rather than bluetooth.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send SMSes from my computer through an Android phone?](http://superuser.com/questions/86076/how-do-i-send-smses-from-my-computer-through-an-android-phone)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/449328/how-can-i-send-sms-from-my-pc-using-my-android-phone-galaxy-s3, http://superuser.com/questions/176818/how-can-i-send-sms-from-my-pc-using-my-iphone?lq=1

Comment: I agree those are some solutions. Most of them are internet based. Or involve downloading apps through 3rd party sources. Are there any Play store friendly apps? Keep in mind, I don't want to do this over the internet, I want to do it over bluetooth.

Comment: Just because you don't like the existing answers doesn't mean it's not the same question. You even say yourself some of those are solutions, and that not all require the Internet.  To get newer/different answers, consider placing a comment and [a Bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing question.

Comment: @Frantumn have you found out how to do it?

Comment: Not the way I want to. I don't want an internet based solution.

Answer (score -2):

Simply Download SMS Center on your android phone from play store. It works as you want it. except for the calls and headset option. you can send sms and you will get notifications as well.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smscontrolcenter&hl=en

Comment: This is a copy of another answer.